# jQuery menu system

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Would anyone know of a jQuery menu plugin that is similar to this style of menu: http://demo.7studio.eu/joomla/fp/#

It has nice animation, transparency, supports icons for menu elements and menu item can be a HTML form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HoverIntent: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

They made that menu with some sort of delay. HoverIntent plugin can accomplish what you want, with some time.